# How can I make this matrix of permutations more efficiently?

Tags: matlab, matrix, permutation

I have written this code:

```
a = repelem(ones(7,8)-2.*eye(7,8), 7:-1:1, 1);
for i=1:7
    a(i,i+1)=-1;
end
for i=8:13
    a(i,i-5)=-1;
end
for i=14:18
    a(i,i-10)=-1;
end
for i=19:22
    a(i,i-14)=-1;
end
for i=23:25
    a(i,i-17)=-1;
end
for i=26:27
    a(i,i-19)=-1;
end
for i=28:28
    a(i,i-20)=-1;
end
```

To produce this matrix:

```
-1  -1   1   1   1   1   1   1
-1   1  -1   1   1   1   1   1
-1   1   1  -1   1   1   1   1
-1   1   1   1  -1   1   1   1
-1   1   1   1   1  -1   1   1
-1   1   1   1   1   1  -1   1
-1   1   1   1   1   1   1  -1
 1  -1  -1   1   1   1   1   1
 1  -1   1  -1   1   1   1   1
 1  -1   1   1  -1   1   1   1
 1  -1   1   1   1  -1   1   1
 1  -1   1   1   1   1  -1   1
 1  -1   1   1   1   1   1  -1
 1   1  -1  -1   1   1   1   1
 1   1  -1   1  -1   1   1   1
 1   1  -1   1   1  -1   1   1
 1   1  -1   1   1   1  -1   1
 1   1  -1   1   1   1   1  -1
 1   1   1  -1  -1   1   1   1
 1   1   1  -1   1  -1   1   1
 1   1   1  -1   1   1  -1   1
 1   1   1  -1   1   1   1  -1
 1   1   1   1  -1  -1   1   1
 1   1   1   1  -1   1  -1   1
 1   1   1   1  -1   1   1  -1
 1   1   1   1   1  -1  -1   1
 1   1   1   1   1  -1   1  -1
 1   1   1   1   1   1  -1  -1
```

I'm looking for a more efficient way to produce this matrix. One way to do so is:

```
S=[-1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
P=unique(perms(S),'rows');
```

But I don't want to use permutation at all because I want to use this code and make matrices with bigger dimensions and using permutation makes it impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by @gnovice is excellent, however I'd like to add an alternative answer for pedagogical purposes. As gnovice states *"You're producing every permutation of positioning 2 values of -1 in a 1-by-8 vector of ones"*. We can apply this to our problem by thinking about how we can generate successive permutations of `[-1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1]`.

Coming from `C++`, this is very intuitive as the `algorithm` library offers `std::next_permutation` which generates the next [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) permutation of your vector. The algorithm is quite simple and can be found here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation. In fact, a much more generalized version of this algorithm has been implemented in `matlab` by [Jos](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/profile/authors/870065-jos-10584). We will utilize `nextperm_local` that can be found at the very bottom of the "Functions" tab on the file exchange page for [nextperm](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/57429-nextperm-v-k).

```
myP = [-1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1];

function P = nextperm_local(P)
    k1 = find(P(2:end) > P(1:end-1), 1, 'last');
    if isempty(k1)
        k1 = 0;
    else
        k2 = find(P(k1)<P, 1, 'last');
        P([k1 k2]) = P([k2 k1]);
    end
    P((k1+1):end) = P(end:-1:(k1+1));
end

total = nchoosek(8, 2);
output = zeros(total, 8);

for i = 1:total
    output(i,:) = myP ;
    myP = nextperm_local(myP) ;
end
```

And produces the following matrix:

```
output =

  -1  -1   1   1   1   1   1   1
  -1   1  -1   1   1   1   1   1
  -1   1   1  -1   1   1   1   1
  -1   1   1   1  -1   1   1   1
  -1   1   1   1   1  -1   1   1
  -1   1   1   1   1   1  -1   1
  -1   1   1   1   1   1   1  -1
   1  -1  -1   1   1   1   1   1
   1  -1   1  -1   1   1   1   1
   1  -1   1   1  -1   1   1   1
   1  -1   1   1   1  -1   1   1
   1  -1   1   1   1   1  -1   1
   1  -1   1   1   1   1   1  -1
   1   1  -1  -1   1   1   1   1
   1   1  -1   1  -1   1   1   1
   1   1  -1   1   1  -1   1   1
   1   1  -1   1   1   1  -1   1
   1   1  -1   1   1   1   1  -1
   1   1   1  -1  -1   1   1   1
   1   1   1  -1   1  -1   1   1
   1   1   1  -1   1   1  -1   1
   1   1   1  -1   1   1   1  -1
   1   1   1   1  -1  -1   1   1
   1   1   1   1  -1   1  -1   1
   1   1   1   1  -1   1   1  -1
   1   1   1   1   1  -1  -1   1
   1   1   1   1   1  -1   1  -1
   1   1   1   1   1   1  -1  -1
```

Answer (score 2):

You're producing every permutation of positioning 2 values of `-1` in a 1-by-8 vector of ones. Therefore, you can generate the column indices of the `-1` values using [`nchoosek`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html), then modify the matrix `a` in a single indexing step using [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
indices = nchoosek(1:8, 2);
N = size(indices, 1);
a = ones(N, 8);
a(sub2ind([N 8], [1:N 1:N].', indices(:))) = -1;
```

And the output:

```
a =

    -1    -1     1     1     1     1     1     1
    -1     1    -1     1     1     1     1     1
    -1     1     1    -1     1     1     1     1
    -1     1     1     1    -1     1     1     1
    -1     1     1     1     1    -1     1     1
    -1     1     1     1     1     1    -1     1
    -1     1     1     1     1     1     1    -1
     1    -1    -1     1     1     1     1     1
     1    -1     1    -1     1     1     1     1
     1    -1     1     1    -1     1     1     1
     1    -1     1     1     1    -1     1     1
     1    -1     1     1     1     1    -1     1
     1    -1     1     1     1     1     1    -1
     1     1    -1    -1     1     1     1     1
     1     1    -1     1    -1     1     1     1
     1     1    -1     1     1    -1     1     1
     1     1    -1     1     1     1    -1     1
     1     1    -1     1     1     1     1    -1
     1     1     1    -1    -1     1     1     1
     1     1     1    -1     1    -1     1     1
     1     1     1    -1     1     1    -1     1
     1     1     1    -1     1     1     1    -1
     1     1     1     1    -1    -1     1     1
     1     1     1     1    -1     1    -1     1
     1     1     1     1    -1     1     1    -1
     1     1     1     1     1    -1    -1     1
     1     1     1     1     1    -1     1    -1
     1     1     1     1     1     1    -1    -1
```